# Can an SVG vector graphic be converted to a PNG file format for use in Fireworks?

Tags: graphics, vector, svg, image-conversion, fireworks

As many of you know, there are quite a few websites that sell royalty free graphics. Some sites sell vector graphics (svg) or give you the option to download them as such.

I don't have a graphics editor that will support SVG. Currently, I'm working with an older version of Fireworks. I cannot open a SVG file type. (I also cannot afford to purchase PhotoShop or Illustrator software).

I'm running Windows on my PC.

**Questions**:

- What are my options?
- Is there a SVG to PNG converter?
- Would the converted file retain everything correctly?
- Would I be able to work with the converted SVG file as I do a PNG?

Comment: I've come across an open source software called Inkscape (www.inkscape.org). It handles SVG type image files and can export them to PNG format.  :) So I think this will be my solution when it comes to buying the SVG graphics.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd recommend downloading [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), which is the freeware equivalent of Illustrator. It can export svg to png, and it uses SVG as its native image format.

Comment: This doesn't export vectors to png though for fireworks - only as bitmap

Comment: @Darbio Now I'm just confused. Isn't .png raster (which in my mind is the same as bitmap) only and incompatible with storing vector information? What were you expecting it to do vector wise when creating a .png file?

Comment: Fireworks PNG (.fw.png) used to store vector information. Irrelevant now, 13 years on, given it’s been discontinued.

Answer (score 17):

1. open the SVG file with IE
2. right click the picture in the IE web page
3. 'save as' PNG file

Comment: Worked perfectly for me with IE11 on Windows 10, and far easier than other proposed solutions if you still have IE installed.

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer. In Windows 10, I opened my svg file in Edge > click "..." menu > click "Reload in Internet Explorer mode" to then right click on the image and "Save As" png. Super simple, no other software needed.

Comment: @DanielT this is a very good suggestion. In addition, in the newer versions of Edge, you need to allow "Reload in internet Eplorer mode" from settings. Otherwise, you cannot see it in the menu.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to guess you're on Windows, but on Linux I use [librsvg2-bin](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=librsvg2-bin).

Then use `rsvg-convert -o output.png input.svg`

A quick google search brought me this if you're only going to be able to use Windows: http://www.openclipart.org/wiki/SVG_Tools

Comment: In my tests so far, rsvg-convert has succeeded where other tools and apps have failed.

Answer (score 1):

For a single image, if you do not want to install any additional SW, you can do the following (on Windows, should work on Linux similarly):

1. Open the svg in a text editor and asjust the `width` and `height` attributes of the `<svg></svg>` node to your needs
2. Open in any program which can open svg files (any browser should do)
3. Make a screen shot of the icon (and possibly little bit surrounding area): `<WINDOWS><SHIFT>S`
4. Paste the screen shot into paint
5. Crop the image to the actual image
6. Save as PNG (or something else)