# Download C3 chart as pdf as given download option in D3 graphs

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graph, c3.js

I'm working on product where I generated C3 chart successfully. But problem is that I'm not able to download these graph as pdf or png. Even I don't know C3 libraries are providing this features.

Please suggest me if there is any way to download c3 chart as pdf or png. I want to download particular graph by clicking on button as d3 graph. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that those libraries are rendering your graphs as SVG, inline in the page. What you need is a way to get the rendered SVG (plus styles), and then if necessary to convert it to a PNG / PDF.

If you only want to do it every once in a while, this is something you can do by hand. There is [a bit of [semi-official documentation](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6466603) from D3's creator on the subject. You can also have a look at the answers to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019462/how-to-convert-svg-files-to-other-image-formats) other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064310/can-an-svg-vector-graphic-be-converted-to-a-png-file-format-for-use-in-fireworks).

---

If you want to do it programmaticaly, as a "Download this chart" feature on your site, there are multiple ways to go:

- You can use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to render your graph server-side, save the SVG and then use a tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to convert it to PNG.
- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) can render your page and take a screenshot of the chart. Here is very similar [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632748/svg-to-png-server-side-using-node-js) with a good answer using PhantomJS.

Comment: Thanks, Now I'm using jspdf but I'm not rendering the image of graph inside the pdf. Can you help me?

Comment: I don't know much about JSPDF, but it seems to be able to render images into the PDF. If so you just need to extract your SVG as a data URI. Have a look at the first answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567668/svg-to-canvas-with-d3-js

Comment: I'm getting the pdf but graph is not rendering.Just see my code.. var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#chartbar03').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});

Answer (score 0):

Note:  If the chart looks correct on canvas, I assume the following would work with C3 or any other chart:

I found that since I have to support IE 11 I instead went with canvas to blob to PNG using "canvas-toBlob.js" and "FileSaver.js"

```
$("#save-btn").click(function() 
{
    $("#myChart").get(0).toBlob(function(blob) 
    {
        saveAs(blob, "chart_1.png");
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mfvmoy64/155